# Rendered image files are unreadable files without specification

Tags: export

I'm super confused!
I'm exporting a scene in Blender (Cycles render) as PNG's (500 frames).
But the files that are produces are not PNG's, they are just files without specification. I also tried JPG's but it gives me the same unreadable files.
I usually use Blender render without any problems.

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong?
I would really love to get an answer.

thanx everybody :)

dirk

Comment: btw: I also tried to export as avi. But again it gives me an unreadable file. Im sure i'm doing something stupid, but i cant figure out what. I have a scene with a house on an Island in an ocean (ocean modifier) No extremely demanding settings (i think).... i'm completely lost :(

Comment: You need to enable file extensions in the render output panel

Answer (score 1):

How about checking the "File Extension" option?

[image]

[image]

Comment: user2049010 , you are a frickin' genius! (and i am an idiot) I was stressing out like crazy, and you casually saved my deadline! I don't know why that got unchecked, but checking it totally solved it. Thnx Brah!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. Can you "accept" my answer please? thx!

Comment: sure, but...how do i do that?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

thx!